# How to mark a non-returning function in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there an attribute to mark a function that always throws an exception or dies?

```
/** @noreturn */
function customDie() {
    die();
}

function bar() {
    switch( .. ) {
        case 1: customDie();  // <-- should not warn because there is no break
        case 2: xxx();
}

/** @return int */
function goo() {
    ...
    customDie();  // <-- should not warn that the method is not returning an integer
}
```

Comment: lack of a break technically shouldn't warn anyways - there are plenty of uses for fall-through switch statements that the false positives wouldn't be worth the warnings.

Comment: Break fallthrough is rare, and should always be documented as intentional - there is an attribute for that. Also, break was just one example - same analysis is used when a function that suppose to return an integer ends with the customDie().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP 8.1 or later, you can use [the `never` return type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.never):

```
<?php

    function customDie(): never {
        die();
    }
```

PhpStorm won't warn about not returning values when calling `customDie()`, it won't see the `switch`-`case`-example above as fall-through and it will mark code following a `never` function call as dead.

If you are using PHP 8.0 (or any older version<sup>1</sup>), you can use the custom `NoReturn` attribute [since PhpStorm 2020.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-4/#noreturn):

```php
<?php

    use JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn;

    #[NoReturn]
    function customDie() {
        die();
    }
```

PhpStorm will then treat `customDie()` as an exit point.

---

<sup>1: While attributes are only supported starting with PHP 8.0, PhpStorm will still understand them even in earlier versions, though it will warn you that attributes require PHP 8.0.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "attribute"/functionality in current versions of PhpStorm. Please follow this ticket for details: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10673

The only option I can suggest is to add actual `die();` after calling such function. Yes -- one extra line, but only 1 extra line which will never actually be executed anyway.